# How to activate callback on modal confirmation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I need some very basic help. Basically, im trying to create a Modal Confirmation dialog, and i've got most of it down. Simply put, it's a dialog asking "Are you sure?" with two buttons "Yes" and "No"

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height:140,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Yes": function() {},
            "No": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

What do i so that when "yes" is hit, the box closes and finished running the script i want?
It maybe a newb thing, but i'm learning as i go, and not in any particular order

Update 1

New code:

```
$('#stats_ensaves').click(function(){
        $('#thedialog').dialog('open');
        return false;
    });
    $('#thedialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 300,
        buttons: {

            "Confirm": function(){
                $("#stats_ensaves").dialog("open");

            },

            "Cancel": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");

            }
        }
    });
```

stats_ensaves is right here: `<span class="playerstat">Energy Saves: </span>
    <span id="stats_ensaves"><a href="http://www.galatium.net/account.php?onnow=N" id="link"><b>ON</b> (7 left)</a></span>`

My new question is: Why isn't the confirm button linking me to that link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What script do you want to run?  It's not shown nor referenced. I'll assume it's called `myFunction`.

here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gillyspy/gECNQ/)

Note: please tag these as **jquery-ui**

Comment: Ok this helps a lot. Just one question. In myFunction how do i call the script that was interuppted by the dialog;'

Comment: I thought it was clear as you could set some variable in the button handlers that is in closure for the handler and `interruptFunction` and examine that var.  Or why return to it at all? Why not have whatever you're going to do in `myFunction`?   

Perhaps you're one of these people tha prefers a promise/committment model.  Here's a [fiddle for that](http://jsfiddle.net/gillyspy/ktpKF/)

Answer (score 0):

```
...
        buttons: {
            "Yes": function() {
                // some code here when yes was clicked
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
             },
            "No": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".confirm").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var targetUrl = $(this).attr("href");
    var $dialog-confirm = $('<div></div>').
        html("<p>Are you sure?</p>").
        dialog({autoOpen: false,
        title: 'Please Confirm',
        buttons : {
            "Yes" : function() {....},
            "No" : function() {....}
        },
        modal: true
    });

    $dialog-confirm.dialog("open");
});
```

Comment: Funnily enough, i need to figure out what goes in the "Yes" : funtion(){....} <---